# pdfmanagement-testphase tikz babel and dvips

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, dvips, tikz-fadings

This code don't work with compilation in dvi->ps->pdf

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase} % load the package
\DocumentMetadata{} % activate the PDF management (with options)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=transparent!0 , outer color=transparent!100]
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%\fill[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
%\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I use Texlive2021 et Miktex 21.12.10 up to date (27/01/2022)

Comment: you get same with pdflatex not just latex/dvips (active French !)

Comment: pdftex xetex and luatex works, it's just latex/dvips

Comment: it fails for me with same error, however just tracing now....

Comment: @ManuelCart it errors for me with pdflatex too. With `\shorthandoff{!}` it compiles (but without output naturally).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, your right, it fail with pdflatex too!

Comment: it is a bug in the xcolor patches. I will  fix it.

Comment: I uploaded a new version to ctan with a fix. And if you find other problems you can also report them in the github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 0.95k (2022-01-28) of pdfmanagement-testphase fixes the problem.